# << operator overloading in C++ for logging purposes

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have a C++ class where I place many std::cout statements to print informative text messages about a mass of signals that this class is handling. My intentition is to redirect these text messages to a function named log. In this function, I have flag named mVerbose which defines if the log text should be printed. The content of this function is as follows:

```
 void XXXProxy::log(std::stringstream& ss)
 {
   if(mVerbose)
   {
     std::cout << ss;
     ss << "";
   }
 }
```

Then, the caller code snippet to this function is as follows:
     std::stringstream logStr;

```
 logStr << "SE"
        << getAddr().toString()
        << ": WAITING on epoll..."
        << std::endl;      
 log(logStr);
```

I would like to overload the << operator in my XXXProxy in a way that I can get rid of creating a std::stringstream object and calling the log function. I want to be able to log the text messages as below and let the << operator aggregate everything into:

```
 << "SE"
 << getAddr().toString()
 << ": WAITING on epoll..."
 << std::endl;
```

So I wouldlike to have an member << function that looks like:

```
 void XXXProxy::operator << (std::stringstream& ss)
 {
   if(mVerbose)
   {
     std::cout << ss;
     ss << "";
   }
 }
```

**QUESTION**

I am relatively a novice C++ developer and get lots of compilation errors when attemting to write the above stated like << operator. Could you please make some suggestions or direct me to some links for me to correctly implement this << operator. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use [Boost.Log](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial.html)?

Comment: `XXXProxy` seems to violate the principle of single responsibility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want to use `std::cout` directly and you want to have your own Log class, you could implement a simple wrapper providing the same interface of `std::ostream`: **operator<<**:

```
class Log {
private: 
    std::ostream& _out_stream;

    //Constructor: User provides custom output stream, or uses default (std::cout).
    public: Log(std::ostream& stream = std::cout): _out_stream(stream) {} 

    //Implicit conversion to std::ostream
    operator std::ostream() {
        return _out_stream;
    } 

    //Templated operator>> that uses the std::ostream: Everything that has defined 
    //an operator<< for the std::ostream (Everithing "printable" with std::cout 
    //and its colleages) can use this function.    
    template<typename T> 
    Log& operator<< (const T& data) 
    {
        _out_stream << data;
    }
}
```

So if you implement `std::ostream& operator>>(std::ostream& os , const YourClass& object)` for your classes, you can use this Log class.

The advantage of this approach is that you use the same mechanism to make `std::cout << your_class_object` work, and to make the class work with the Log.

### Example:

```
struct Foo
{
    int x = 0; //You marked your question as C++11, so in class initializers 
               //are allowed. 

    //std::ostream::operator<< overload for Foo:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os , const Foo& foo)
    {
        os << foo.x;
    }
};

int main()
{
  Log my_log;
  Foo my_foo;

  my_foo.x = 31415;

  my_log << my_foo << std::endl; //This prints "31415" using std::cout.
}
```

### Possible improvements:

- You could write a `extern const` of class Log, and make the class implement a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). This allows you to access the Log everywhere in your program.
- It's common in log outputs to have a header, like *`Log output (17:57): log message`*. To do that, you could use `std::endl` as a sentinel and store a flag that says when the next output is the beginning of a line (the beginning of a log message). **Checkout [the next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17605306/1609356) for a complete and working implementation**.

### References:

- [std::ostream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream)
- [operator<< for std::ostream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2)
- [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)
- [std::is_same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)
- [decltype specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)

Comment: When writing non member `<<`, its better to put in the namespace of the struct than global namespace

Comment: @balki yeah, its true. I don't know why I have writted it as global in this answer xD. I always write this as non-member friend in the class scope.

Comment: @Fardaarda you ask, we try to help you. Thats stackoverflow :) If you have any question, put comments here.

Comment: This time stampmarker (Log output (17:57)). How do we enable the class Log to capture it automatically for us? Or is it the user of the class that should manage it? Thnx.

Comment: @Fardaarda comment answered bellow

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33313/discussion-between-farda-arda-and-manu343726)

Answer (score 8):

The timestamp of the example was only that, an example :).

But if you like that, we could try to implement it. Thankfully to C++11 and its STL's big improvements, we have an excellent time/date API: [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

`std::chrono`is based in three aspects:

- **Clocks**
- **Durations**
- **Time points**

Also, chrono provides three types of clocks, `std::system_clock`, `std::steady_clock` , and `std::high_resolution_clock`. In our case, we use `std::system_clock` (We want access to the date-time, not meassuring precise time intervals).
For more info about std::chrono, checkout [this awsome Bo Qian's youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M13otPgOePs&list=PL5jc9xFGsL8FWtnZBeTqZBbniyw0uHyaH&index=12).

So if we have to implement a time stamp for our log header, we could do this:

**EDIT:** Like other good things, C++ templates are good tools until you overuse it.
Our problem was that `std::endl` is a templated function, so we cannot pass it directly to
annother templated function as parammeter (`operator<<` in our case), because the compiler cannot deduce std::endl template argumments directly. Thats the recurrent error *"unresolved overloaded function type"*.

But there is a much simpler way to do this: **Using an explicit overload of `operator<<` for `std::endl` only, and other templated for everything else:**

```
class Log
{
private:
    std::ostream& _out_stream;
    bool         _next_is_begin;

    const std::string _log_header;
    using endl_type = decltype( std::endl ); //This is the key: std::endl is a template function, and this is the signature of that function (For std::ostream).

public:
    static const std::string default_log_header;

    //Constructor: User passes a custom log header and output stream, or uses defaults.
    Log(const std::string& log_header = default_log_header , std::ostream& out_stream = std::cout) : _log_header( log_header ) , _out_stream( out_stream ) , _next_is_begin( true ) {}

    //Overload for std::endl only:
    Log& operator<<(endl_type endl)
    {
        _next_is_begin = true;

        _out_stream << endl;

        return *this;
    }

    //Overload for anything else:
    template<typename T>           
    Log& operator<< (const T& data) 
    {
        auto now        = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto now_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t( now ); //Uhhg, C APIs...
        auto now_tm     = std::localtime( &now_time_t ); //More uhhg, C style... 

        if( _next_is_begin )
            _out_stream << _log_header << "(" << now_tm->tm_hour << ":" << now_tm->tm_min << ":" << now_tm->tm_sec << "): " << data;
        else
            _out_stream << data;

        _next_is_begin = false;

        return *this;
    }
};

const std::string Log::default_log_header = "Log entry";
```

This code snippet works perfectly. I have pushed the complete implementation [to my github account](https://github.com/Manu343726/Cpp11CustomLogClass).

### Reference:

- [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)
- [std::chrono::system_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock)
- [std::chrono::system_clock::now()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now)
- [std::time_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t)
- [std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/to_time_t)
- [std::tm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm)
- [std::localtime()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime)

Comment: The code examples above are not compiling. I appreciate if you can provide compiling solutions. Thanks.

Comment: why there are no `return`'s at the ends of operators' implementations?

Comment: @peetonn just typos, sorry

Comment: This is almost correct, you should be returning `*this` from any function with `Log&` as the return signature.